# Fill MS-Access Table depending on another column with ComboBox and LIKE statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, where-clause, lookup

I need to fill my MS Access Table with new names; I think an example would explain it the best:
This is my Table1 that I want to add the country names for. Please mind, that the column "Common Name" is something like a "free input field", so it can contain any string (not useful as a key)

```
| Common Name                            | Country      |
---------------------------------------------------------
| new Samsung Galaxy A3                  |              |
| used Apple iPhone XS 64 gb in black    |              |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my table that contains the new names:
Table2:

```
| String  | Country |
---------------------
| Samsung | Japan   |
| Apple   | USA     |
---------------------
```

I need access to fill in the "Country" field in Table1. Also it needs to be a combobox so that I can check if the correct row source is set, so 
I am looking for a Lookup field, that changes it's row source depending on another column with something like an "LIKE" statement, so i can preserve the relationship. I already searched for other solutions with UPDATE and SELECT WHERE LIKE statements, they didnt work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query with a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.[Common Name], 
        (Select First(Country) 
        From Table2 
        Where Table1.[Common Name] Like "*" & Table2.String & "*") AS Country
FROM 
    Table1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What in this occasion is "tblParent"? I assumed both (Table1 or Table2), it did not work. It shows me every column of Table2.

Comment: That was a left-over from my test. Corrected now.

Comment: Thank you, the lookup works. How can I update the result into my Table1? Access tells me that "the query needs to be updateable".

Comment: You may have to write/copy the output from the query above to a (temporary) table, then use this in an update query.